# Getting a bunch of a's as my output and program crashes. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: mips

```
## Question:
## Swap each pair of elements in
## the string "chararray" and
## print the resulting string.
## There will always be an even number
## of characters in "chararray".
##
## Output format must be:
## "badcfe"

#################################################
#                       #
#       text segment            #
#                       #
#################################################

    .text       
        .globl main
main:       # execution starts here

# Any changes above this line will be discarded by
# mipsmark. Put your answer between dashed lines.
#-------------- start cut -----------------------

la $t1, chararray
la $t2, chararray 


nextCh: lb $t0, ($t1) # get a byte from string
        lb $t3, ($t2) #get a byte from string


        beqz $t0, strEnd   #zero means end of string

        add $t2, 1
        sb $t3, ($t1)
        sb $t0, ($t2)
        add $t1, 1

        j nextCh

strEnd: la $a0, chararray
        li $v0, 4
        syscall


        li $v0, 10
        syscall


#--------------  end cut  -----------------------
# Any changes below this line will be discarded by
# mipsmark. Put your answer between dashed lines.

#################################################
#                                               #
#               data segment                    #
#                                               #
    #################################################

        .data
chararray:
    .asciiz "abcdef"
endl:   .asciiz "\n"

##
## End of file loop4.a
```

I'm pretty new to this stuff. I think I'm not cycling through the array properly or maybe I am using the instructions wrong. What do you guys think?Do you have any ideas? The program continues to crash.

Comment: What you're doing wrong is not using a debugger.  That will tell you which instruction you crashed on, and let you examine regs / mem.  You can even single-step one instruction at a time.  Writing asm without a debugger is like building a robot while blindfolded.  That said, you did do an ok job of describing exactly how your program fails, and there are some comments, so maybe someone that wants to debug your code for you will be able to answer pretty easily.

Comment: And of course, since the code apparently is written to be executed in SPIM/MARS, you don't even need to find a debugger since the simulator has one built-in just waiting for you to make use of it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
        la   $t3, chararray
nextCh:
        lb   $t0, 0($t3)  # even byte
        lb   $t1, 1($t2)  # odd byte

        beqz $t0, strEnd  # end of string?

        sb   $t0, 1($t3)  # swap bytes
        sb   $t1, 0($t3)

        add  $t3, 2       # advance by 2 bytes
        b nextCh
```